# Error while reading data from database in c#

Tags: c#, json, sql-server

I have an error in this code. I deserialize a JSON file and stored that data in the database now I want to show that data from my database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using ReadingFromDb.Dto;

namespace ReadingFromDb.Controller
{
    public class StudentController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetStudents()
        {
            using (var context = new UNIEntities1())
            {
                var query = @"Select ";
                var dbQuery = context.Database.SqlQuery<StudentDto>(query);
                var list = await dbQuery.ToListAsync();
                return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

> JSON can not be used like method.

What should I do?

Comment: This looks like code from an ASP.NET MVC project - is that correct?

Comment: Did you store the data in json format? If yes then why are you returning it as `return Json()` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this error you can try as below

```
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
      // your code
     }


    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetStudents()
    {
        using (var context = new UNIEntities1())
        {
            var list = await context.StudentDto.ToListAsync();
            return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your contoller must be extend the base class Controller in which the [`Json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) virtual method is available:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to extend your `StudentCotroller` with `Controller` then put your code under that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using ReadingFromDb.Dto;

namespace ReadingFromDb.Controller
{
    public class StudentController:Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetStudents()
        {
            using (var context = new UNIEntities1())
            {
                var query = @"Select ";
                var dbQuery = context.Database.SqlQuery<StudentDto>(query);
                var list = await dbQuery.ToListAsync();
                return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```